# bootstrap button circle shadow issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im created the `bootstrap button circle`, but my button is not like a google gmail app button,  i want to  create  like this button using my code,  look my **example image**
 [image: example image]

im try to do it, but  my button not like google gmail app button 
how to make like this button, please help me to fix this
thanks

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px; background-color: #b89981;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;   border-radius: 35px;


}
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">+ </button>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The colour? The size? The position? Be specific.

Comment: sir,no no, i want create  likea google gmail app type button

Comment: _"but my button like a 3d"_ - are you saying that you want to remove the shadow?

Comment: sir i need to  button without 3d, i know its a box-shadow effort , actually i want to make look my sample image, this google button is very attractive

Comment: So why cant you just edit the box-shadow? Sorry, I don't understand what you  are asking.

Comment: im try to using box-shadow, but its a not good method,i want to google button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152140/discussion-between-core114-and-turnip).

Comment: Here's the 'official' shadow: box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i resolve the problem

This is my code
im used this
`border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.25);`

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px; background-color: #b89981;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;   cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
 .btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.33; cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl"><img src="Image/add-btn-icon.png">x </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 0.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #b51313;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 3px 1px 10px #252020;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">x</button>
```